# Using grep in Linux to get two strings and sort only based on one

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, grep

My file looks like this:

```
BSS 00:1a:1e:5b:8b:21 (on wlan0) -- associated
    TSF: 39741405897 usec (0d, 11:02:21)
    freq: 2437
    beacon interval: 100
    capability: ESS ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime (0x0421)
    signal: -71.00 dBm
    last seen: 104 ms ago
    Information elements from Probe Response frame:
    ...
    ...
    ... 
BSS 00:1c:1c:5a:8e:23 (on wlan0)
    TSF: 397414345497 usec (0d, 11:02:21)
    freq: 2433
    beacon interval: 100
    capability: ESS ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime (0x0421)
    signal: -76.00 dBm
    last seen: 104 ms ago
    Information elements from Probe Response frame:
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

And so on.
(It's basically the output of `iw dev wlan0 scan`).

Now I want to get only `BSS 00:1a:1e:5b:8b:21` and `signal: -72.00 dBm` (on the same line), and the lines should be sorted based on the `signal` part. Could anyone please help me with the grep command I should use?

Thank you.

Comment: It sounds like you also want those two lines to be concatenated into a single record.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly... Like this:

BSS 00:1a:1e:5b:8b:21 (on wlan0)
signal : -72.00 dBm,

BSS 00:1b:1e:5b:8b:23
signal : -73.00 dBm
etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `awk` followed by `sort`

```
awk '/^[ ]*BSS/ {p=1; a=$1" "$2} p && /^[ ]*signal/ {p=0; a=a" "$0; print a}' file | sort -n -k4
```

Output for your sample input file

```
BSS 00:1c:1c:5a:8e:23     signal: -76.00 dBm
BSS 00:1a:1e:5b:8b:21     signal: -71.00 dBm
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it is not working :( I have updated the question with more details of how precisely my file looks like. Please check it.
Hence I am not sure how to pin point which column BSS and signal part belong to use awk command. If you are not able to see the format correctly in he question, please try this command in terminal if you have Ubuntu installed: 'sudo iw dev wlan0 scan'

Comment: @SrikanthKandalam Please check updated answer. Just needed to take care of leading spaces.

Comment: @SrikanthKandalam that command gives me *nl80211 not found.* error so can't test with it but working fine with your updated input in question